# Service Endpoint Interface - Publish several objects

Tags: java, soap, endpoint

I developing a server which naturally could be split into several classes like Person, Car and store(toy example). This would make the code much easier too read since all methods would not be in the same file. However,

> _serviceEndpoint1 = Endpoint.publish(address, Person);
>   _serviceEndpoint2  = Endpoint.publish(address, Car);

causes a crash because both objects are published on the same address.

I found that this problem could be escaped by publish the objects at different addresses like  `address/Person` and `address/Car`but then the client need to connect too different URL's. Is that a drawbacks on the client side and are there any other drawbacks by this approach or is this how it is done?

Comment: There's rarely a "this is how it's done" solution for something. It's up to you (or the person who programs the client) to determine whether it's a drawback or not.

Comment: True! If the client side just want to handle one URL to this server, must all methods then be in the same class? I guess it is yes when I read it myself!